# odd behavior of print within mapply

Tags: r, printf, mapply

I am seeing some unexpected behavior (to me anyway) when `print()` is included as a side effect in a function wrapped in `mapply()`.

For example, this works as expected (and yes I know it's not how we add vectors):

```
mapply(function(i,j) i+j, i=1:3, j=4:6) # returns [1] 5 7 9
```

And so does this:

```
mapply(function(i,j) paste(i, "plus", j, "equals", i+j), i=1:3, j=4:6) 
# returns [1] "1 plus 4 equals 5" "2 plus 5 equals 7" "3 plus 6 equals 9"
```

But this doesn't:

```
mapply(function(i,j) print(paste(i, "plus", j, "equals", i+j)), i=1:3, j=4:6)
# returns:
# [1] "1 plus 4 equals 5"
# [1] "2 plus 5 equals 7"
# [1] "3 plus 6 equals 9"
# [1] "1 plus 4 equals 5" "2 plus 5 equals 7" "3 plus 6 equals 9"
```

What's going on here? I haven't used `mapply()` in a while, so maybe this is a no-brainer... I'm using R version 3.4.0.

Comment: Looks right to me.  The first three outputs are the result of printing each `mapply` iteration, and the last line is the final output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` both prints its argument and returns its value.

```
p <- print("abc")
# [1] "abc"
p
# [2] "abc"
```

So each element gets printed, then the vector of stuff gets returned (and printed). Try e.g. `invisible(mapply(...))` or `m <- mapply(...)` for comparison.

FWIW `cat()` returns `NULL` ...

Comment: `cat()` needs `cat(...,"\n")` (explicit line-end)